# How to send bundles directly to top MEV builders?

Tags: flashbots, mev, mev-boost, mev-searcher

I can send my bundles to Flashbots builder successfully. However, there are only about 20% of blocks are built by Flashbots builders, other blocks are mainly built by builder0x69, beaverbuild, and bloXroute. The success rate of bundle transactions being included in Ethereum largely depends on which builder I send my bundle to, right? bloXroute provides Cloud-API to send bundles to its internal builder and other external builders, but how to send bundles to the main builders (builder0x69, beaverbuild, and bloXroute) directly?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://www.mev.to/builders/ for a list of top builders on mainnet. All of these builders support eth_sendBundle call to receive MEV transactions.